# libbfd-2.22.so missing while compiling Binutils/Glibc/Zlib

Tags: compiling, libraries, make, lfs

When I try to compile Binutils, Glibc and Zlib using chroot on my [LFS](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/) system, I get this error:

> ar: error while loading shared libraries: libbfd-2.22.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I compiled Binutils before without using chroot, the files libbfd.a, libbfd.so, libbfd-2.22.so and libbfd.la exist both in /tools/lib/ and /usr/lib/

I don't know where the compiler is searching for it.
How to continue compilation?

Comment: In Ubuntu current version, I need symlink:

sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libbfd-2.24.51-system.20140727.so /usr/lib/libbfd-2.24-system.so